# How to use OpenCL lib with SPIR-V?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, opencl

I have successfully used OpenCL with VS2015 to write and execute a `.cl` program. I'm now trying to convert it to OpenCL C++ by following [these guidelines](https://github.com/OpenCL/OpenCLCXXPortingGuidelines/blob/master/OpenCLCToOpenCLCppPortingGuidelines.md), which mentions:

> To compile OpenCL C++ kernel language to SPIR-V user have to use compiler that is not a part of OpenCL framework. The Khronos Group provides reference [offline compiler based on Clang 3.6](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIR/tree/spirv-1.1) and an implementation of OpenCL C++ Standard Library called [libclcxx](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/libclcxx).

How can I adapt these installation instructions to VS2015?

Comment: @Quentin Yes, i tryied. To compile `cl` file, i must use SPIR compiler. But i don't understand, how i can use together two compiler, gcc for host file, and spir-v for cl file.

Comment: @Quentin No, not cl.exe. `To compile OpenCL C++ kernel language to SPIR-V user have to use compiler that is not a part of OpenCL framework. The Khronos Group provides reference offline compiler based on Clang 3.6 and an implementation of OpenCL C++ Standard Library called libclcxx.`

Comment: I have made a substantial rewording of your question to give more context. Feel free to correct, modify or even discard it to your taste. Also, you should replace that broad last sentence with a description of where exactly you got stuck trying.

Comment: @Quentin oh, thank you. Now it's more correct. I will wait for an answer

Comment: Which hardware vendor is this for, are you using the AMD App SDK? See [this thread](https://community.amd.com/message/2859382#comment-2859382), AMD indicates they are not supporting OpenCL and SPIR-V.  But apparently AMD is now pursuing ROCm.  The Intel toolkit does offer a SPIR-V compiler for Windows, invoked as ioc64 -cmd=compile -spirv64 if you're interested in running OpenCL on the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using OpenCL, you should understand how the code is divided. There is a portion of the code that runs under the *host* environment, and then there is the *device* code.

In your example, you can use VS2015 to compile the host code using the MSVC compiler, linking against the OpenCL runtime libraries. However, MSVC will not support compiling the *kernel* code, whether it be C or C++.

To compile the kernel code, you can either use the OpenCL runtime libraries (ie, clCreateProgram followed by clBuildProgram), if they support the source language. Additionally, some (most) OpenCL devices support an *intermediate* representation of kernel code. One of these intermediate representations that is universal is SPIR-V. Thus, you are able to load an arbitrary SPIR-V representation of a kernel, assuming it meets all the OpenCL requirements.

So what the instructions are telling you to do is to compile you ".cl" file using an external tool to the OpenCL runtime itself into a SPIR-V representation, and then load that representation (clCreateProgramWithIL followed by clBuildProgram) with the OpenCL runtime.

How you do this specifically is up to you. One method would be to use the modified Clang compiler provided by Khronos:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIR/tree/spirv-1.1

Once you have that built (pretty easy if you have git and cmake already installed), you can invoke it within VS2015 using a custom build tool/step (whichever you prefer).